# Will typescript wait for a loop to complete before executing the next code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop, asynchronous

I'm trying to wrap my head around async methods.  Other actions don't wait for async methods unless you use await.

What about for loops?  Does typescript wait for the completion of a for loop before proceeding?

Example:

```js
   mergeQueries(start, end) {
     for (let i = 0; i < end.length; i++) {
        if ((start.includes(end[i].id)) && (!this.dontShowList.includes(end[i].id))) {
            this.allItineraries.push({
              id: end[i].id,
              startDate: end[i].startDate,
              endDate: end[i].endDate,
              userId: end[i].userId,
            });
        }
     }
     if (this.allItineraries.length < 1) {
       console.log('presentAlertInformation');
       this.presentAlertInformation();
     }
   }
```

at the end of the query I'd like to evaluate this.allItineraries after the for loop.  It may take a while if it's processing 10's of thousands of users.  if the length is < 1 I'd like to present an alert but will it wait until the completion of the for loop?

Comment: Loop is a synchronous function and and javascript will execute the loop first and then execute the next instructions.

Comment: There isn't any apparent asynchronous functionality in your example...  what operation are you expecting to execute asynchronously?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I was referring to the for loop.  I was wondering if the loop operation would finish before before the next operation in the example and Sohail answered.

Comment: I see.  I would just point out one caveat-- if there is any asynchronous operation being executed in the loop _without_ an `await`, then the loop will complete and the  `if (this.allItineraries.length < 1) {` block might execute _before_ the asynchronous operation has completed.  But yes, basically all standard JS operations are synchronous by default unless you take steps to explicitly make them asynchronous, such as leveraging promises, `setTimeout`/`setInterval` or `async`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with TypeScript, but if you wish to await for the completion of each asynchronous activity within a loop, the [for-await...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) is an option. That is the only loop I am aware of to “pause” execution within the actual loop. That is to say, without using a loop to push a bunch of promises into an array, then resolve each member of collection with `Promise.all`/`bluebird.reflect` or something.

**NOTE:** Apparently the babel configuration of StackOverflow's "snippet" implementation will choke on this, but [here it is on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbyvtz).

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    list: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    (async () => {
      const iterable = [
        simulateLongRunning(1),
        simulateLongRunning(2),
        simulateLongRunning(3)
      ];
      let list = [];
      for await (let item of iterable) {
        list = list.concat(<li>{item}</li>);
      }
      this.setState({ list });
    })();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.list ? "not finished yet" : <ol>{this.state.list}</ol>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```